# XOR encryption/decryption and compliance

Tags: encryption, cryptography, pci-compliance

XOR encryption/decryption is very basic mechanism where one does not need any keys to encrypt.

I have used this for file encrypt/decrypt in C++. The file contains secure data. The file is divided into many fixed sized chunks and different characters are used to encrypt different chunks getting me a encrypted file.

I would like to know two things:

1. if there is another way to encrypt it more securely?
2. is such mechanism acceptable if PCI compliance is considered?

I cannot add support of any crypto library like openssl etc. to my current environment.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've somewhat answered your own question.  XOR "encryption", if you can call it that, should **never** be used in production code.  At an academic level, it provides an excellent example of a broken encryption scheme that inexperienced cryptographers can perform cryptanalysis on.  Past that, it is useless.  Contrary to what you state, however, XOR encryption does require a key.

The industry standard symmetric encryption algorithm at the time of writing is AES.  AES is used in many widespread protocols like TLS and SSH.

XOR encryption is also definitely not acceptable for things like PCI compliance.

Comment: I don't think the answers to this question tell the whole story about this mysterious "XOR encryption". If we simply mean one time pad then it does in fact provide perfect secrecy. However, it is rather impractical for general-purpose encryption for multiple reasons (key requirements, malleability). It can still be used in practice in some scenarios, e.g. for secret sharing.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes there is a more secure way to encrypt a file: AES (Advanced Encryption Standard).
2. Since there is no secret key this is not encryption, it is obfuscation. There is little to no security, security is not obtained by using a secret method.
3. This is not PCI compliant, see  [PCI Security Standards](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org).
4. ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "*Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.*"

Answer (score 0):

XOR encryption is not secure at all. It is trivial to break and can be done on pretty much any device.

It is not suitable for PCI compliance. OWASP provides some guidance here:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cryptographic_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Rule_-_Use_strong_approved_cryptographic_algorithms

For C++ there are a number of libraries that can do the encryption for you - use these and don't implement it yourself as you will get it wrong! Some libraries to look at are OpenSSL and libgcrypt.